# Можно ли так написать в сочинении?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Чувство правды зависит от нравственного воспитания.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение корректно, если оно в целом соответствует  теме сочинения.

**Чувство правды** – неоднозначное понятие.  Поэтому должно быть ясным,  что именно вы имеете в виду, как это связано с раскрытием темы.
Справочная информация по теме:  [https://kartaslov.ru/каким-бывает/чувство%20правды](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82/%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D1%8B).

Скорее всего, имелось в виду нравственное чувство.

Но  любое чувство – это **интуитивное** восприятие жизни.   С одной стороны, оно свойственно собственной природе  человека, но и от воспитания тоже зависит.

Другое дело, что  **воздействовать на чувства** нужно умело,  так как только логикой и  стандартными моральными поучениями здесь не обойдешься.  К каждому человеку нужен особый подход.

Answer (score 0):

Что именно вы хотите этим сказать или подчеркнуть? (без грубости) Вы сами понимаете смысл Вашего предложения? Что именно Вас в нем не устраивает? По моему мнению, здесь все хорошо!